# centering word wrapped kerned text

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a custom control and wanted to make it generic enough to use any orientation. When I try vertical orientation the kerned text isn't centered.
You can see that best with the character 'i' in the attached image.
Any suggestions?

[image: centering kerned text]

Here's how I'm rendering the text:

```
  int flags = Qt::AlignJustify | Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::TextWrapAnywhere;
  painter.drawText( TextArea, flags, text );
```

painter is a QPainter. This code is in the paintEvent() method.

Comment: I didn't think vertical text could be kerned. Can it?

Comment: To do it properly, you'd have to kern vertically, I think. That is probably not what the Qt library is trying to do, though.

Comment: It's the horizontal spacing of the text that I'd like to fix. I think it's centering the rectangle the text is render in not each letter of the the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a linefeed after each character might do the trick.

**Update:**

Also, I think you should remove the `Qt::AlignJustify` flag. I didn't notice before that you were missing the horizontal centering flag. Try these flags:

```
int flags = Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::TextWrapAnywhere;
```

or

```
int flags = Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::TextWrapAnywhere;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a Qt function that achieves what you want. However you could paint it letter by letter. Here is how you could do it:

```
 QFontMetrics fm = painter.fontMetrics();
 QString t = "Sample";

 // Loop through all letters
 int topX = 5;
 int topY = 5;
 int yOffset = 0;

 for (unsigned i=0; i<t.count(); i++)
 {
   QChar c = t.at(i);
   // Get metrics
   int w = fm.width(c);
   int h = fm.height();

   painter.drawText(topX-w/2, topY-h/2, QString("%1").arg(c));

   topY = topY + h + yOffset;
 }
```

**How it works**

- Get the font metrics in order to calculate the width and height of every letter.
- `topX, topY` are the center coordinates of your first letter in painter coordinates
- `yOffset` is the vertical distance between the letters
- For all letters get their width and height.
- Draw them at the correct position. Since when text is drawn we give its top left position, we give it with respect to its center in order to have it centered
- Increase topY by the previous letter's height and the y offset
- TODO: Check that the drawn text is within widget's boundaries...

**EDIT**

A second approach that draws the text within a given rectangle:

- Split the initial rectangle into n sub rectangles where n the number of letters in the provided string.
- Paint each letter to the center of the corresponding sub rectangle
- The advantage of this method is that the text is drawn within a given bounding rectangle so it can fit vertical controls...

Sample code:

```
/* Let rect the rectnagle in which we want to draw the vertical text
and t the string we are drawing. rectH is the height of every sub-rectangle */
double rectH = rect.height() / (double) t.count();
for (unsigned i=0; i<t.count(); i++)
{
     QChar c = t.at(i);

     // Draw every char in the corresponding sub rectangle
     painter.drawText(QRect(rect.topLeft().x(),
                rect.topLeft().y() + i*rectH,
                rect.width(),
                rectH),
              Qt::AlignCenter,
              QString("%1").arg(c));

}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do it the hard way. Thanks very much for the code.